# Datatable.Select with max(col) and WHERE clause?

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with the following data.

```
Week    Score           Rank
1       75.8300000000   1
2       76.6800000000   9
3       79.8787870000   4
4       0               0
5       0               0
6       0               0
7       0               0
...
53      0               0
```

If the datatable only had the first 3 weeks (weeks with Rank), then the following line would work perfectly. But now I need to add a WHERE clause that gets MAX(Week) where Score is greater than 0. In this case, the row returned would be Week 3. Essentially, the query would be SELECT max(week) From *datatable* where Rank > 0

```
DataRow[] dr = dsRanks.Tables[0].Select("Week = MAX(Week)");
```

I tried the following, but I get an index error because 0 rows are returned.

```
DataRow[] dr = dsRanks.Tables[0].Select("Week = MAX(Week) and Rank > 0");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where `weeknum` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you want the data row with the highest numbered week that has valid data.  Something like this should do it:

```
var dr = dsRanks.Tables[0].Select("Rank > 0", "Week ASC"). LastOrDefault();
```

As per your example dr is the data row for Week 3.

Comment: Thanks. That worked, and LastOrDefault() to avoid the "Sequence contains no elements" exception.

Comment: @user2520528 Glad I could help. If you don't have any more issues, please remember to mark this answered. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It's easier to solve using LINQ instead:

```
var week = dsRansk.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("Rank") > 0)
    .Max(row => row.Field<int>("Week"));
```

Comment: How do I cast week as DataRow[]?

Comment: @user2520528 You don't, because it's not a data row array, it's an integer.  There is no way to cast an integer to a data row array.  If you want the given row representing that week you can use `OrderByDescending` instead of `Max` and then `Take(1)` or `First` on that result, if you prefer.